# perl script to check 2 byte unicode is not working

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8

My perl script is not finding the unicode character in the name below.

```
Helen Mon‘ea
```

When I viewed the above name in UTF-8, it shows as x91

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
@ARGV >= 2 or die "Usage: \n======\n\tperl $0  <Accepted Record Length> <File-Name> 
For example, 
    perl /opt/apps/scripts/IdentUnicodChar.pl 576 <Actual File Name>\n";
$RECL = $ARGV[0];
$filename = $ARGV[1];
if ( @ARGV == 3) {
  $Flag_Print= $ARGV[2];
} else {
  $Flag_Print= "NoPrint";
}
open(FILE, $filename) or die "Could not read from $filename, program halting.";
$count = 1;
$First = Y;
while (<FILE>) {
    if (length($_) != $RECL) {
        if ( $Flag_Print eq 'print' ) {
            print $_;
            print "\n--------------------------- \n";
        }
        if ( $First eq 'Y' ) { 
            $First = N;
            print $.;
        } else {
            print ", ";
            print $.;
        }
    }
    $count++;
}
close FILE;
print "\n";
```

I tried using the below and `binmode(STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)");` but it is not helping or detecting this unicode character

```
use utf8;
```

Comment: Tip: Never use global vars for nothing! (`open my $FILE, ...`)

Comment: Tip: Never use two-arg `open`! (`open my $FILE, "<", ...`)

Comment: x91 isn't valid UTF-8, so the following claim of yours makes no sense: "When i viewed the above name in UTF-8, it shows as x91"

Comment: `N` and `Y` are barewords. It will work as a string literal, but it can also be a function or a constant, and using it is a bad idea. You should use quotes `'N'`

Comment: Tip: ALWAYS use `use strict;` (or equivalent). It prevents so many errors.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami, will incorporate all your comments.

Answer (score 3):

Say the file is encoded using UTF-8. You can tell Perl to automatically decode it.

```perl
open( my $fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $qfn )
   or die( "Can't open `$qfn`: $!\n" );
```

Better yet,

```perl
use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";

open( my $fh, "<", $qfn )
   or die( "Can't open `$qfn`: $!\n" );
```

In addition to setting the default encoding for uses of `open` in its lexical scope, the pragma adds a decoding layer to STDIN and an encoding layer to STDOUT and to STDERR so we can print decoded text to them without encoding first.

```perl
while ( <$fh> ) {
   chomp;
   say sprintf "%vX: %s", $_, $_;
}
```

Produces

```
48.65.6C.65.6E.20.4D.6F.6E.2018.65.61: Helen Mon‘ea
```

U+2018 is the code point for LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (`‘`).

---

What if your file isn't UTF-8, though? You claim it is, but you also say `‘` is encoded as 91. Those claims are contradictory.

`‘` is encoded as `91` by [cp1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), a encoding commonly used by Windows in the US. You can use that encoding instead if it's more appropriate.

---

You also talk of identifying lines containing Unicode Code Points which require two bytes to encode using UTF-8. For that, you can use

```perl
while ( <$fh> ) {
   if ( my $count = tr/\x{80}-\x{7FF}// ) {
      say "$. contains $count 2-byte characters.";
   }
}
```

Keep in mind that the encoding of U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (`‘`) is three bytes long (`E2 80 98`).

Comment: Understood about two byte and three byte unicode characters. 
I Added the code, 
open( my $fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $qfn )
   or die( "Can't open `$qfn`: $!\n" );

Output from command ====>
UTF-8 "\x91" does not map to Unicode at /opt/apps/scripts/IdentUnicodChar.pl line 57, <$fh> line 99.
100
Can you please tell me how to add three byte unicode check in addition to two byte unicode check?

Comment: Again, you don't have a UTF-8 file as you claim. That is why you are getting that error. Possibly cp1252? This is already addressed by the answer.

Comment: The Code Points encoded using three bytes by UTF-8 are U+800 to U+FFFF (inclusive).

Comment: i am reading the file in UTF-8 in Datastage. We dont have cp1252 NLS map in Datastage. I dont know how to send the screenshot, when i view that  LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (‘)  in notepad++ it is showing as x91.
But i understood this is three byte unicode character after you explained

Comment: I know the file contains `91`. There's no doubt about that. And the file isn't encoded using UTF-8. There's no doubt about that either.

Comment: can you tell me the how to check two byte and three byte unicode characters present in any line in this perl script?

Comment: @Vamperl, ***We dont have cp1252 NLS map in Datastage***--An [old post](http://www.dsxchange.com/viewtopic.php?t=109283) about Datastage suggests there is an `MS-1252` encoding you can set.